# Checkbox selected items not updating database

Tags: checkbox, django-forms, django-queryset

I was trying to pick list of items in a table and assign them to a new table. I'm able to pick and display the query set but it doesn't update into database. Maybe there is some error in the code. The form gets saved but the object list is not saved. The traceback is attached. The query set is not saving into database. Is this related to Foreignkey values? Appreciate some advise or alternatives

**Models.py**

```
class BidItem(models.Model):
bid = models.ForeignKey(Bid, related_name='bids', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
order= models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
quantity = models.ForeignKey(OrderItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)

def bid_price(self):
    return self.price * self.quantity
```

**Views.py**

```
def bid_list(request):
    """Place bids"""
    selected = request.POST.getlist('vendorbid')
    selected_orders = OrderItem.objects.filter(pk__in=selected)

    if request.method == 'POST':
            form = BidListForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                bid = form.save()
                for item in selected_orders:
                    BidItem.objects.create(bid=bid,
                                            order = item['order.id'],
                                            product=item['product'],
                                            price=item['price'],
                                            quantity=item['quantity'])


                return render(request,'bids/bid_placed.html')
            else:
                return render(request, 'bids/bid_list.html', {'selected_orders': selected_orders, 'form': form})
        else:
            form = BidListForm()
            orders = OrderItem.objects.all()

            return render(request, 'bids/bid_list.html', {'form': form, 'orders': orders})
```

**Error and traceback**

The error I get is:
TypeError at /bids/bid_list/
'OrderItem' object is not subscriptable

Trace back is:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved as there were foreign keys I had to change the variables accordingly:

Here is the resolved part in views.py for anybody's reference:

**Views.py edited part**

```
BidItem.objects.create(bid=bid,
                                    order=item.order,
                                    product=item.product,
                                    price=item.price,
                                    quantity_id=item.quantity)
```